# Convert CAD based on known Local Origin Point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, datum, cad

I have CAD files which were created in a "Staten Island local datum". There is no spatial information associated with these files, just annotation mentioning the datum. After researching this datum, I discovered that it's origin is located at N 137,190.02, E 1,967,746.81, according to the NAD_1927_StatePlane_New_York_Long_Island_FIPS_3104 coordinate system.

Given this info, how do I get these files to line up with the rest of my data? Do I need to create a custom projection?

Comment: By googling I found a few mentions of a [Staten Island Datum](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Staten+Island+datum%22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this essentially following the instructions from mkennedy here: [Create custom projection using either QGIS or ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34501/create-custom-projection-using-either-qgis-or-arcgis-desktop?rq=1)

I found the .prj file for NAD_1927_StatePlane_New_York_Long_Island_FIPS_3104, and modified the false easting and westing until my data lined up.

Original 1927 NYLI State Plane:
PROJCS["NAD_1927_StatePlane_New_York_Long_Island_FIPS_3104",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1927",DATUM["D_North_American_1927",SPHEROID["Clarke_1866",6378206.4,294.9786982]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",2000000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",100000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-74.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",40.66666666666666],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",41.03333333333333],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",40.5],UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192],AUTHORITY["EPSG",4456]]

Modified custom projection:
PROJCS["Staten_Island_Local",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1927",DATUM["D_North_American_1927",SPHEROID["Clarke_1866",6378206.4,294.9786982]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",11898.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",-57566.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-74.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",40.66666666666666],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",41.03333333333333],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",40.5], UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192]]

FYI - PolyGeo's answer would have worked if I had even one projected CAD file to base a custom projection. Unfortunately, I didn't have this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a custom coordinate system then there is an Esri [How To: Create a custom projection file to align CAD Data in ArcMap 10.1 and above](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012038) that should be useful:

> The instructions provided describe how to create a custom projection
>   file for CAD data, and how to align the CAD file with other data in a
>   projected coordinate system with units of feet, meters, or other
>   linear units in ArcMap 10.1 and above.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have time to work through this tomorrow. I'll let you know if it works.